# Customizing outlook forms locally

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-form

Is it possible to customize Outlook forms locally on users' computers without using exchange for deployment? We developed an addin for outlook, a small customization needs to be done on the clients that the addin will be deployed, but we won't be using Exchange for deployment of the customized forms. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Personal forms are published either to a folder or to your Personal Forms library.
Take a look at this msdn page it has a section "Publishing Custom Forms"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155722(office.10).aspx